# How to calculate transformation matrix

Tags: math, graphics, rotation

I am rendering views of a mesh model from fixed points, i.e. I am virtually putting the camera at a known coordinate in world space. For example, see the image below:
[image]

I will place the camera at each red vertex for which I know the coordinates. How can I work out the transformation matrix of the camera. For example, if the position I wish to move it to is `(x,y,z)` then I know the translation is obviously `[x,y,z]`. However, it also has to face `(0,0,0)` which means it must be rotated, I just don't know how to calculate this rotation.

I essentially want to recover the 4x4 transformation matrix of the camera which will look like

```
|r11 r12 r13 0|
|r21 r22 r23 0|
|r31 r32 r33 0|
| x   y   z  1|
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [`gluLookAt`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) or `D3DUtil_SetViewMatrix`?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you have a camera orientation associated with its state.  This orientation is often captured as a View Plane Normal (VPN) and a View Up Vector (VUV).  It may at times be useful (but not essential) to also have a View Right Vector (VRV) or View Left Vector (VLV) which is just the cross product of the two others.

In order to rotate the camera from one position **V**<sub>0</sub> = (x, y, z) to another **V**<sub>1</sub> = (x', y', z') while having it maintain the perspective that it is looking towards (0, 0, 0) you just need to apply the rotational portions of your transformation to the various view vectors.  Since you're simply rotating the camera position across the surface of a sphere, this should preserve the point toward which the camera is being pointed.

To compute this, the rotation vector is **R** = **V**<sub>0</sub>×**V**<sub>1</sub> (may have the order wrong... but this should give you the idea) and the angle is given by θ = cos<sup>-1</sup>[(**V**<sub>0</sub>∙**V**<sub>1</sub>) / ||**V**<sub>0</sub>|| ||**V**<sub>1</sub>||].  You can use either [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) or an [Angle-Axis Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle) to rotate the camera's position and orientation.

Alternately, if you're using OpenGL, there is a function which does this already for you.  It's called [gluLookat](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml).  I don't know if it's been deprecated in favor of something else, but back in the day, it was very useful.

Comment: I have found a method on the vtkCamera class (I am using vtk btw) which is `vtkCamera::GetViewTransformMatrix` which returns a 4x4 matrix. Could this be what I'm looking for? Also, why is it 4x4 should this not be a 3x3 rotation matrix?

Comment: According to the vtkCamera docs, you should probably be using GetViewUp/SetViewUp and GetViewPlaneNormal/SetViewPlaneNormal.  That will let you determine the current orientation of the camera and change it as desired.  The view transformation matrix is going to be quite a bit more cumbersome to manipulate.

Comment: 4x4 matrices are used when you want to mimic the behavior of a 3D affine transformation.  Translation is not a linear transformation, since all linear transformation must map the origin onto itself.  To get around this, another dimension is added to the 3D vectors with a 1 in that place.  This permits matrices to be used to perform translation.  In the case of rotation, it is a pure linear transformation, and so the extra dimension isn't needed.

Comment: May I suggest http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-4-geometry/